# How to find Invoice detail counter column not in numeric order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an invoice detail table, that has a Invoice_ID and a Detail_id associated with each invoice.  Example:

```
Detail_ID      date_Created       Invoice_id       Description
   1           1/1/18 12:02:03       1            Service 1
   2           1/1/18 12:02:04       1            Service 2 
   3           1/1/18 12:02:05       1            Service 3
   4           1/1/18 12:06:03       2            Service 1
   5           1/1/18 12:06:04       2            Service 2 
   6           1/1/18 12:06:05       2            Service 3
   7           1/1/18 12:08:03       3            Service 1
   8           1/1/18 12:08:04       3            Service 2 
   9           1/1/18 12:08:05       3            Service 3
  10           1/1/18 12:12:03       4            Service 1
  12           1/1/18 12:12:05       4            Service 3
```

What i'd like to do, is query the sample data, and return the `"Invoice_id"` that has a `"Detail_ID"` that is not in sequential order.  For example - Notice above, `Invoice_id` 4, goes from `detail_id 10` to `detail_id` 12.  How can I do this?

Comment: Nothing in your data is called `ticket_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer assumes that `ticket_id` is really `invoice_id`.)

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `lag()`.  If I assume that there are no duplicate `detail_id`s, then you can do:

```
select id.invoice_id
from invoice_detail id
group by id.invoice_id
having count(*) <> max(id.detail_id) - min(id.detail_id) + 1;
```

Basically, this checks that the number of records matches the range given by the minimum and maximum values.

Comment: I'm interested to pick your brain on the "lag()" - Are you available to have a quick chat session?