# How to Check ID Column to see if it exists, based on having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have an existing question, that I thought would lead me my answer, but now i'm left with another question, and i'm not sure how to solve it.  My original quesiton is here: [How to find Invoice detail counter column not in numeric order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512814/how-to-find-invoice-detail-counter-column-not-in-numeric-order)  In my table I have the following information when I run the query

```
Select * from Invoice_detail where Description like 'Service%'
```

Result:

```
Detail_ID      date_Created       Invoice_id       Description
   1           1/1/18 12:02:03       1            Service 1
   2           1/1/18 12:02:04       1            Service 2 
   3           1/1/18 12:02:05       1            Service 3
   4           1/1/18 12:06:03       2            Service 1
   5           1/1/18 12:06:04       2            Service 2 
   6           1/1/18 12:06:05       2            Service 3
   7           1/1/18 12:08:03       3            Service 1
   8           1/1/18 12:08:04       3            Service 2 
   9           1/1/18 12:08:05       3            Service 3
  10           1/1/18 12:12:03       4            Service 1
  12           1/1/18 12:12:05       4            Service 3
  13           1/1/18 12:15:05       5            Service 1
  15           1/1/18 12:15:05       5            Service 2
```

`Select * from Invoice_Detail returns`:

```
Detail_ID      date_Created       Invoice_id       Description
   1           1/1/18 12:02:03       1            Service 1
   2           1/1/18 12:02:04       1            Service 2 
   3           1/1/18 12:02:05       1            Service 3
   4           1/1/18 12:06:03       2            Service 1
   5           1/1/18 12:06:04       2            Service 2 
   6           1/1/18 12:06:05       2            Service 3
   7           1/1/18 12:08:03       3            Service 1
   8           1/1/18 12:08:04       3            Service 2 
   9           1/1/18 12:08:05       3            Service 3
  10           1/1/18 12:12:03       4            Service 1
  12           1/1/18 12:12:05       4            Service 3
  13           1/1/18 12:15:05       5            Service 1
  14           1/1/18 12:15:05       5            Test
  15           1/1/18 12:15:05       5            Service 2
```

The query for my initial question - I'm running is:

```
select id.invoice_id
from invoice_detail id
where Description like ('Service%')
group by id.invoice_id
having count(*) <> max(id.detail_id) - min(id.detail_id) + 1;
```

This query, which was answered in my previoius question is doing exactly what I asked for - However, I found some special cases, where this issue pops up. 
I'd only like to return `invoice_ID` 4 ONLY (above) In this Case - Detail_ID '11' does not exist and was presumably deleted.  I do not want to see Invoice_id 5, since the `detail_id` Exists, just not for that ticket.

I'm almost thinking I need something like this, too: 
[SQL: find missing IDs in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389605/sql-find-missing-ids-in-a-table)

Comment: Isn't that what your query does?

Comment: I edited the question.  My query will return both 4 and 5.  Notice the "where" clause

Comment: not following.  **return invoice_ID 4 ONLY in the event that Detail_ID 11, does NOT exist in the table. I do not want to see Invoice_id 5, since the detail_id Exists, just not for that ticket.**

Comment: Hopefully that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just remove the `where`:

```
select id.invoice_id
from invoice_detail id
group by id.invoice_id
having count(*) <> max(id.detail_id) - min(id.detail_id) + 1 and
       sum(case when Description not like 'Service%' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The second condition makes sure that all the rows that the service that you want.

Comment: The where clause is needed, as I only want to see specific results sets of where a Detail_ID was deleted - Not necessarily used by another ticket_ID.  So basically, I want to know - when a ticket has only services that I filter by is not sequential AND that Detail_ID(s) that would make it sequential don't exist in the table.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE filters what goes into the aggregates, HAVING filters the aggregates themselves. You are using HAVING to do something that really is a WHERE, so try this (edited to note: I just tested this, and it does work):

```
select id.invoice_id
from invoice_detail id
where Description like ('Service%')
and id.invoice_id in 
(
select id.invoice_id
from invoice_detail id
group by id.invoice_id
having count(*) <> max(id.detail_id) - min(id.detail_id) + 1
)
group by id.invoice_id;
```

Hope this helps.